# MySQL aggregate sum of count

Tags: mysql

I have a simple group by query:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(users)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY users
```

How do I add a sum_each_day column that will sum the users count of each row and will aggregate it forward to the next row and so on

The output should be like this:

```
timestamp | users | sum_each_day
2015-11-27  1          1
2015-11-28  5          6
2015-11-29  3          9
2015-11-30  7          16
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have timestamp or a date field? because I dontt see you agregated by timestamp

Comment: Paste database explain DDL

Comment: It's a date field and I am counting the users on each day

Comment: @RagenDazs what do you mean by DDL ?
There are only two columns : timestamp and users
I just want to count the users each day and aggregate the totals on the following day on

Comment: It is strange to see a `group by` on a column that is being aggregated in the `select` list, while the column that is not aggregated is not listed in the `group by`. Neither is allowed in standard `sql`. Makes it hard to understand, and I wonder if it is intended.

Comment: @Abraham at MySQL console past de result of  `explain database_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT    timestamp,
          num_users,
          (SELECT COUNT(users)
           FROM   my_table
           WHERE  timestamp <= main.timestamp) sum_users
FROM      (
          SELECT   timestamp,
                   COUNT(users) num_users
          FROM     my_table
          GROUP BY timestamp
          ) main
```

Comment: Instead of timestamp.. you problably need something like `from_unixtime(mytimestamp, '%Y %D %M')`

Comment: OP want both column `COUNT(users)` and `SUM(users)`

Comment: @trincot I have tried it but the new select count user column bring me 0 value

Comment: @trincot BINGO ! this is it :)
Thank you very much !
BTW, if I would like to add third column to this query in the future, let say the name is 'area' how should I integrate it here ?

Comment: Adding a column really depends on how you want to aggregate it, because you are now showing one result per timestamp, but at the base you have multiple records per timestamp. So if you have an extra field to show, you need to decide whether you want the sum of it, the maximum of it, ... etc. Assuming that `area` is numeric and you want the sum per timestamp, then add `SUM(area) sum_area` next to `COUNT(users) num_users`, and select `sum_area` at the top. The principle is similar with `max`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this in mysql it'll cost some performance but i believe a sub query with a count will solve it:

SELECT t1.timestamp, count (*), select count (*) from my_table t2 where t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp From my_table t1 Group by users

If you display this data through a scripting language like PHP it would be easier to keep a counter and display the aggregate per row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty, this will work:

```
set @c=0;
SELECT `timestamp`,sum(`users`),(select @c:=@c+sum(`users`))
FROM `my_table` 
group by `timestamp`;
```

Comment: you understand me right but the new sum of users column returns exactly the sam as the count column

Comment: @Abraham I've tested the query and it returns exatly same result as you've posted in output. Are you using InnoBD storage engine?

Comment: Ivichunk , yes I am using tInnoBD storage engine

Comment: @Abraham Then sorry, this example works fine for me and I don't know what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using variable:

```
SET @total := 0;
SELECT timestamp, DayCount, (@total := @total + DayCount) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT timestamp, COUNT(users) AS DayCount
     FROM my_table
     GROUP BY timestamp) AS t1
```

[Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c160f/5): I am not using your table structure here, but you can get idea